# Are there any options for inverting a bezier curve? (cytoscape.js)

Tags: javascript, bezier, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to shape my edges similarly to this:

static mock of desired edges/curves

[image: static mock of desired edges/curves]

I'm able to create "S" shaped curves, but i would like them to invert when going downwards from the root node (similarly to the picture). I haven't noticed anything in the docs that describes settings to do this.

I have a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l5m6mnlqrz

What could also work is if I were able to smooth out the 90 degree curve with the "taxi" curve-style, although this doesn't seem possible.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you asked on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cytoscape-helpdesk first?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry, i did not. i will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create desired form using single Bezier curve, because central range should be vertical. But two conjugated curves might provide appropriate result.

For points A (left one), and B (it is not important - whether B point is lower or higher than A):

The first curve have starting point `P0=(XA, YA)` and ending point `P3=((XA + XB)/2, ((YA + YB)/2)`

The first control point must lie at the same horizontal as starting point, the second one - at the same vertical as ending point

```
X1, Y1 = X0 + DX, Y0
X2, Y2 = X3, Y3 - DY
```

Parameters `DX and DY` define rounding of right angle. 
Try to set them as `DX = (X3 - X0) / 3` and `DY = (Y3 - X0) / 3`m then vary denominator to get desired curve form

The second part is mirrored curve with points

```
 (X3, Y3), (X3, Y3 + DY), (XB - DX, YB), (XB, YB)
```